# Native video players for Android that can support HLS, DRM

Tags: android, android-video-player, drm, http-live-streaming

I'm researching options for native android players available today that can support features such as HLS and DRM.

I've come across Google's ExoPlayer and NexStreaming's NexPlayer. Could anyone provide some more alternatives? Preferably open source ones.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're after is WideVine DRM, it's installed by default on all (modern) Android devices, and media players can make use of it transparently. For example, if ExoPlayer bumps into a a DRM-protected MPEG-DASH presentation, it will automatically call into the platform's built-in [MediaDrm](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDrm.html) implementation for license acquisition and for decryption. And this built-in implementation happens to be WideVine for most devices.

If you're after other DRM schemes such as PlayReady, you're out of luck with open-source solutions, and you need to go proprietary.